# Poor performance when streaming large data set from asp.net core

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, streaming

I have a WPF application that is communicating directly with a database (SQL Server hosted in an Azure VM) and I need to replace that direct communication so all the database calls instead go through a webservice. So I have created a simple ASP.NET Core 5 api with a controller that executes queries and then streams the data back to the client. The controller is essentially as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/StreamDataSet")]
public IEnumerable<object[]> StreamDataSet()
{
    //get request details from header
    var procedureName = Request.Headers["Procedure"];
    var serverName = Request.Headers["ServerName"];

    using (SqlConnection connection = _dataService.GetConnection(serverName))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = _dataService.GetCmd(procedureName, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
                    reader.GetValues(values);
                    yield return values;
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then to consume it in the client, I'm not even doing anything with the data (at the moment), just receiving it as a stream.

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
{
    using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions();
                    
        var result = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<object[]>(stream, options);
        //do something here with the received data
    }
}
```

When I run the both the client and the server on my dev workstation, requesting an arbitrarily large data set (300K records) it takes around 30 seconds to return the data from the server. That is already not very good when I compare with direct database communication from the client which can do it in about 15 seconds. However I know there is going to be some overhead by going through the webservice, and that response time is just about within acceptable limits.

However when I deploy the webservice into IIS on a separate VM (again in Azure) the performance deteriates massively, with the call taking around 90 seconds to stream all the data.

I believe that the SqlDataReader that is making the call to the database gets the data in binary. So when the service runs on my dev workstation, all the real network traffic is transported pretty quickly in binary. However when the service is deployed into IIS, the network traffic is now all JSON, hence why the performance drops off. The above times are made with gzip content encoding in place, it gets even worse without that.

So what options do I have here? I guess I am looking for some other way to transport the data from the service to the client, without using json? Is there a binary transport I can use? Or do I need to look at using gRPC?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you serialise a huge number of records and send them via http?  You could compress to a file or byte array  and serve that.

Comment: @Andy yes I accept there will be some overhead. But adding a middle tier to serve data has been around for years. I can't believe this type of delay is normal, so I am assuming there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Reading 300,000 records is not "normal". And yes there are ways around this, reducing the size of data being transferred is one obvious one. Or you can cache locally and download changes. Or download whatever they need to work with when they need it. Why is the user sitting there waiting for all that data to arrive?

Comment: @Andy, I guess it depends on the worlds we live in. In my world, 300K records is perfectly normal, and not even large. This is a data portal that takes requests and sources the data for live reporting. It can't be cached as it will go stale.

Comment: I work with millions or rows.  I don't start by downloading them all to the client. If this is reporting on 300k records then run the report on the server.

Comment: @Andy, I work with billions of rows, and that is all handled on the server. With respect, you've got no idea whats going on in this platform, or why the requirements are what they are, and this is a valid requirement in our application. But thanks for your input, I appreciate your time taking to review the question.

Comment: Yeah sure. Yours is bigger than mine. Very productive.  What is the problem with compressing and making it a byte array or file?